# Behavior Driven Development using existing software components

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, bdd, devise

I'm currently reading through the beta version of The Rspec Book: http://www.pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book

It describes The Behaviour Driven Development Cycle (red, green, refactor) as taking small steps during the development process. This means adding features one at a time.

My question is:

If I were to describe a single feature of my software (eg: a successful user login scenario in a cucumber test) AND if I were using a modular component (such as Devise) which has many features (scenarios). How could I possibly follow Behaviour Driven techniques? Once my first step passes, I must reverse engineer my other tests to reflect the functionality of the software component I am using thus violating the principal of BDD!

Edit (for clarity):

My first scenario is passing after implementing Devise. But now I must factor all my subsequent end to end tests (that I have not yet written) around the behaviour of Devise rather than to my stake holder's requirements. So the BDD cycle can no longer be applied. I must reverse engineer Devise in my tests to make them pass or not write the tests.

Comment: I'm still not getting it. If the (only) stakeholder is not interested in Devise's functionality, why are you? If he or she is, why do you object to taking Devise into account in the end-to-end tests? Don't be hung up on the order. You obviously have some code in place. Consider yourself red. Refactor to make the scenario *and the tests* pass. Make sense or am I totally missing something?

Comment: @user156011 I think it's perhaps me that is not getting it. I'd be interested in Devise because it's quicker to use existing, reliable plugins than build everything myself.

Comment: Right. So you *do* use Devise, but you relax from the dogma a bit. You are adding a ton of functionality and your existing tests may break. That's a good thing. When your tests break it's probably because you added Devise and you then can work through each failing example to make sure it's failing for the right reason and to rewrite the example so it passes. Make sense?

Comment: But there are no failing tests. I have all green tests. But to have good test coverage, I must write all my future tests around the functionality of devise. This seems counter productive and not really following BDD. You're right I should relax a bit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BDD cycle involves creating scenarios, then having conversations around those scenarios to discover any more which are missing, any misunderstandings, etc.

If you use a BDD tool like Cucumber, then you can capture the scenarios you've discussed.

Ideally, the scenarios will be in terms of high-level steps, focused on the capabilities of the system and the value they provide to the users. They won't be about logging in or failing to authenticate.

BDD isn't really about testing. It's about learning, and keeping things easy to change. If you're never going to change the mechanisms for logging in then it's enough to manually verify authentication. Focus instead on the things which make your application different to all the other application out there. How does your software actually provide value? How does it communicate with other systems, applications and users? How is money made, or lives saved, or fun had?

If you can answer those questions and keep the steps focused on those, you'll have failing scenarios still, even with Devise. Your scenarios will look more like:

```
Given I have registered an account
When I <do this differentiating thing>
Then I <achieve this differentiating outcome>
```

Logging in will be implicit, and called as a lower level step as part of the first Given.

Comment: I don't agree. BDD is still about *software development*, not only business value. It drives development and avoids accidental features corruption.

Comment: @collimarco BDD is, and always has been, about writing software that matters. If your software isn't driving business value, it doesn't matter. For sure, the answer above doesn't represent canonical BDD, but in my experience focusing on differentiators helps people understand why it's useful to talk through scenarios in the first place. This is based on 9 years of experience having done this stuff, sometimes alongside Dan North.

Answer (score 1):

So I can understand better: You have an existing system and it includes tests but does not include login functionality. You decide to add login:

```
Given a visitor is not logged in
When a visitor goes to the admin page
Then the visitor should see the login page
```

Ok, so then you decide how you want to implement the login because this scenario is failing. Right? So you choose Devise and the scenario passes but all the tests or specs that relied on a security-free system now fail. Am I still on track? If that's the case, you've encountered a case where you are adding a feature that is so pervasive in your application that you need to touch a number of tests/specs to get them all running. You are still testing first because either the code is broken or the test doesn't recognize the new feature. In any case, you know where the work needs to be done.

Helpful?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough but your help is appreciated, of course. I have edited my original question. Does that make things clearer?